# How to use Smart Table

Tags: jquery, angularjs, smart-table

```
var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', ['darthwade.loading', 'firebase', 'ngRoute', 'smart-table'])
```

as you can see I have added dependency of smart table.

Then here is my `HTML`

```
<div class="card">
                            <div class="content">



                                <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
                                            <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
                                            <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
                                            <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
                                            <th>email</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single" ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                                            <td>{{row.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
                                            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
                                            <td>{{row.birthDate | date}}</td>
                                            <td>{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
                                            <td><a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>



                            </div>
                        </div><!--  end card  -->
```

and data in controller

```
 $scope.rowCollection = [
        { firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com' },
        { firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com' },
        { firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com' }
    ];
```

My problem is that smart table's functionality is not working, `stSelectRow` not working, no functionality working. I think im missing Css but I didn't find any `CSS` except `JS` files

Comment: smart table only has minor css needed for the sorting classes on headings and selected row. Those classes are shown in docs. Create a plunker demo that replicates your issue. Any errors thrown in console?

Comment: Also make sure version used is current

Comment: @charlietfl 2.1.8. im reading Docs they said add dependency and then add script files on your html page. thats it. then use Html tags Normally

Comment: that's correct about just adding the html. I assume that is a current version without having to go look it up. Any errors? Beyond that without a demo is hard to help. We can't tell if angular is bootstrapped, if you have a scope problem ...etc

Comment: @charlietfl check this http://plnkr.co/edit/J5LPgH?p=preview 
I have tried plunker given on docs

Comment: @charlietfl how silly Iam, I didn't know that I have to define own `css` with class named `.st-selected` . Problem is solved thanks buddy. can you tell me what else classes I have to defined?

Comment: the sort classses